# SAS Macro - Conditionally print results

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset in SAS that has 22 variable and 345 observation. Variables including CliendID, class(bad or good), duration, purpose, saving_status and.

I want to write a *%client_type* macro that displays all of the following information(observation corresponding to the variable): ClientID, Duration, purpose, Saving_status if the customer has a good credit. And if the customer is not a good credit one (its class is "bad"), it will display the message, "Bad Customer".

The macro %client_status should receive CliendID as parameter(ClientID).

I use the below code but it does not work and I do not have any output when I call the macro (`%client_status(11254858)`).

```
%macro status_client(data,ClientID);
   proc sql;
   select class from project3.dada_credit where ClientID = &CliendID. as Credit;
   quit;

   %let class = Credit;

   %if &class. = "good" %then %do;
      proc print data = data_credit;
      var ClientID duration purpose saving_status;
      run;
   %end;

   %else %do;
      %put &ClientID. "Is a bad credit customer";
   %end;

%mend status_client;
```

How should I correct it?

Comment: Where is &class coming from? It's not mentioned at all in your text or your code.

Comment: The "class" is a variable in my data set that I define it as a micro variable as below. I also define my dataset but I am not sure about that.

%let data = data_set;
%let class = class;

Comment: Why isn't part of the macro parameter list? That isn't good design. But it's also not clear where it comes from. If it's a variable not a macro variable its you can't access the value this way. You need to provide more details about what you *think* is happening here and what you want.

Comment: You should look up the SAS 9.4 macro appendix, there's an example exactly like this, printing a message when a dataset is empty.

Comment: Thank you Reeza. I will check it.

Comment: Suggest you update your question to show a complete example. Show how a value is assigned to &class, show a macro call, and explain what you mean by “does not work”. Are you getting errors in the log, or just an unexpected result?

Comment: Thank Quentin. I try to edit my question and my code. Yet it does not work. I mean I do not receive any output after calling the macro.

Comment: Your PROC SQL is wrong, to make a macro start with working code. Please show an example that would work and we can help make it into a macro.

Comment: Reeza and Tom thanks so much for your kind dedication. I learned a lot of your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem with your use of the current macro is you are calling it without a value for the CLIENTID parameter.  Since you are using positional parameters in the macro call your call is setting the value for the DATA parameter and leaving CLIENTID empty.

I think what you want to do is use the first SQL query to set a macro variable that you can then test in your %IF/%THEN/%ELSE logic.  To set a macro variable with SQL you need to use the INTO clause.  You should initiatize the macro variable in case your SQL query does not find any matching observations.

```
%macro status_client(ClientID,dsn=project3.data_credit);
%local credit ;
%let credit=NOTFOUND;
proc sql noprint;
select upcase(class)
  into :credit trimmed 
  from &dsn 
  where ClientID = &CliendID. 
;
quit;

%if (&credit. = GOOD ) %then %do;
proc print data = &dsn ;
  where ClientID = &CliendID. ;
  var ClientID duration purpose saving_status;
run;
%end;
%else %if (&credit = NOTFOUND) %then %put Client &clientid not found.;
%else %put Client &clientid has &credit credit.;
%mend status_client;
```

Comment: Reeza and Tom thank you very much for your kind advice. I learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is what you want. Your SQL is wrong and you should always start with working code first.

Corrections:

1. Modify the PROC SQL code to create macro variable CLASS
2. Remove %LET which is not required
3. Remove quotes from macro variable comparison as this is text. Note the comparison will be case sensitive.
4. Add a filter for the query to limit the results only to the client, since it wouldn't make sense to print everyones results.
5. Remove the data parameter since it's never used in the macro.
6. Your macro call is incorrect, status_client vs client_status

   ```
   %macro status_client(ClientID);
   proc sql NOPRINT;
       select class into : class from project3.dada_credit where ClientID=&CliendID.;
   quit;

   %if &class.=good %then
       %do;

           proc print data=data_credit;
               WHERE clientID=&clientID;
               var ClientID duration purpose saving_status;
           run;

       %end;
   %else
       %do;
           %put &ClientID. "Is a bad credit customer";
       %end;
   %mend status_client;

   %status_client(11254858);
   ```